# Passing Report Parameters to SubReport in VS 2010 RDLC

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

Passing Report Parameters to SubReport in VS 2010 RDLC

I'm having some troubles defining and passing report parameters to subreports in VS 2010. In VS 2008 in the design view I was able to right click and define the report parameter and have it passed through.

In VS 2010 that prompt is missing. So my question is, how can I pass a value from a parent report to a subreport in VS 2010?

Additionally, this is what is shown in the Report Properties dialog inside of VS 2010:

For the time being I have defined the parameter in the subreport manually in the XML but I'm receiving an error from the main report when I attempt to pass a parameter of any type to the subreport.

The error is :

```
An error occurred during local report processing.

Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value
```

Where I do not have a parameter named value defined anywhere.

Answer (score 23):

- Goto **SubReport** -> **Report Data Pane** -> **Parameters** and add the parameter you want to receive.
- Goto **MainReport** -> **Right-click SubReport** -> **Subreport Properties** -> **Parameters** and add the same paramter name and pick the relevant value from the dropdown.
- Handle the `SubreportProcessing` event and set the datasource for the subreport. In my case the main report datasource was of type `List<Order>` and the parameter was `OrderID`. Sample code below.

```cs
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(SetSubDataSource);
```

```cs
public void SetSubDataSource(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
{
    var mainSource = ((LocalReport) sender).DataSources["MainDataSet1"];
    var orderId = int.Parse(e.Parameters["OrderID"].Values.First());
    var subSource = ((List<Order>)mainSource.Value).Single(o => o.OrderID == orderId).Suppliers;
    e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("SubDataSet1", subSource));
}
```

Comment: **Very Important** The name of the `ReportDataSource` in `e.DataSources.Add` method must match the name of datasource in subreport EXACTLY.

Comment: An alternative to defining subSource like that is using this tag:
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="subSource" runat="server" 
SelectMethod="[The method that selects all your orders]" TypeName="Source.Data">

This will do the same thing and save you those 3 lines of code too.

Comment: If you have multiple subreports and datasources, you'll want to ensure `e.Parameters` isn't null and (if you have multiple params), ensure you're processing that specific report via `e.RportPath`. In my case, there were a dozen subreports and the param was set on a subreport and used in a child subreport, so all other subreports showed `e.Parameters` as empty.