# Subreport returns zero results

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and C# to build an application that queries two databases and then generates a report that also has a subreport.  The main report is passing three parameters to the subreport.  The subreport was coming up blank on every record of the main report.  Because of this I set the NoRowsMessage to "Nothing Returned" to make sure the subreport was indeed displaying.  Now instead of being blank the subreport returns my message.  I have tested the tableadapter by previewing the data and inputting values for the parameters.  The results show up fine.  My guess is that for some reason the parameters are not passing correctly to the subreport.  I have tried setting the parameters to allow null values and also to allow blank values.  Nothing changes.  I have set the LocalReport.SubreportProcessing to a new SubreportProcessingEventHandler.  I set the datasource in that event handler for the subreport.  I don't know what I am missing.  Any suggestions would help.

Here is the code from the Main form

private void JointAgreement_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'termLookup.ACADEMICCALENDAR' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.aCADEMICCALENDARTableAdapter1.Fill(this.termLookup.ACADEMICCALENDAR);
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'yearLookup.ACADEMICCALENDAR' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.aCADEMICCALENDARTableAdapter.Fill(this.yearLookup.ACADEMICCALENDAR);
        }

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string year = comboBox1.Text;
        string term = comboBox2.Text;
        Classes.Functions.GetStudentList(year, term);
        List<ReportParameter> paramList = new List<ReportParameter>();
        paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("Year", year, false));
        paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("Term", term, false));
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(paramList);
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(SetSubDataSource);
        this.joint_Agreement_InfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.jointAgreementInfo.Joint_Agreement_Info);
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }

    public void SetSubDataSource(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    {

        e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("StudentDetail", tRANSCRIPTDETAILBindingSource));

    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: there is a lot of code in the Functions class.  I take information from one database and process it and put the results into another table on the database.  The report is based off of the new table and another table in another database.

Comment: I think I may have made some progress on solving this.  If I add the following line this.transcriptdetailTableAdapter1.Fill(this.studentClasses.TRANSCRIPTDETAIL, year, term, "SomeID"); to the click button event, above the SubreportProcessing line it will populate the subreport with the student whose ID I pass to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually found an answer to my own question.  I didn't know what was wrong so I didn't know what questions to ask.  I found the answer here on stackoverflow at the following link.
[Passing Report Parameters to SubReport in VS 2010 RDLC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388153/passing-report-parameters-to-subreport-in-vs-2010-rdlc)  Thank you everybody who tried to help.