# Getting the error "Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'Subreport1'" while trying to preview a report from Business Intelligence Studio

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I know this question has been asked before, but all questions were for reports being accessed using C# or VB.NET code. My problem is that I am building and accessing the report using Business Intelligence studio, I am basically trying to add a sub report for a report, and I made sure from the parameters and they are OK. However when I try to access the report containing the subreport, I get the error

> Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'Subreport1'.

I also tried deleting the `.data` files but the same problem persisted.

Comment: What about deleting the .data files and doing a full Rebuild Solution?

Comment: I already did that and didn't work :(

Comment: BIDS 2008 says to "Please check the log files for more information."  Did you do this?  If so, I'd love to know where they are on my computer because I cannot find them!!!

Comment: @Andez log files are at your equivalent of `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles`

Answer (score 7):

I faced similar issue in past and in my case below were the culprit's

1. Parameter from main report is sending null value to sub report.
2. Data type of parameter were different than actual data type.

Comment: The second case turned out to be my problem. Thank you. I wish the BIDS error messages were this helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when the dataset’s subreport filters the data by the "Filters" functionality (Filter tab), but when change the filter method by the use of sql parameters (Parameters Tab) it Works.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem when I was not passing the data source for the subreport. This answer helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/8924617/4795214

Answer (score 1):

I was using filters inside the subreport but after doing some research I applied the filter directly into the BindingSource and it worked for me. Here is my code if it helps:

```
Public Sub SubreportProcessingEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SubreportProcessingEventArgs)
        Dim nID As Integer = 0
        Select Case e.ReportPath
            Case "rptBilans_CU"
                nID = e.Parameters.Item(0).Values(0)
                Q_Bilans_CUBindingSource.Filter = "IDPATIENT = " & nID
                e.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSetCompany", Me.DetailSocieteBindingSource))
                e.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", Me.Q_Bilans_CUBindingSource))
            Case "rptBilans_Bacterio"
                nID = e.Parameters.Item(0).Values(0)
                Q_Bilans_BacterioBindingSource.Filter = "IDPATIENT = " & nID
                e.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSetCompany", Me.DetailSocieteBindingSource))
                e.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", Me.Q_Bilans_BacterioBindingSource))
            Case "rptBilans_FNS"
                nID = e.Parameters.Item(0).Values(0)
                Me.Q_Bilans_FNSBindingSource.Filter = "IDPATIENT = " & nID
                e.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSetCompany", Me.DetailSocieteBindingSource))
                e.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", Me.Q_Bilans_FNSBindingSource))
        End Select
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue with sub-reports error:

> Data retrieval failed for sub report.

I found it was in my case everything to do with my login, I was not using SQL Server login and that was the issue it kept on prompting me for login every now and then.

However I deployed the reports all of them 4 sub reports and one main report, went in the troubled sub report and changed the setting for data source 
CREDENTIAL STORED SECURELY IN THE REPORT SERVER

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had was that the `e.ReportPath` name was spelled incorrectly, meaning the `SubreportProcessingEventHandler` could not find the new report I had made.

What happened was I needed to pass a new subreport called "Flasks-NEW" -- and in the subreport properties under "*Use this report as a subreport*" I typed in "Flasks-NEW." I quickly found out that the .aspx.cs file that loaded the main RDLC was still using `e.ReportPath == "Flasks"`, which was causing OP's issue for me.